# php exec() works on some calls, not other similar ones

Tags: php, linux, bash, scripting, ffmpeg

I have a php script that cuts up video. Here are three exec() commands - two execute properly while one does not:

Works:

> sudo ffmpeg -i /home/vidserver/videos/$filename.mp4 -ss $ctime -t 00:00:06 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -y /var/vidcache/test$x.mp4

Works:

> sudo ffmpeg -i /var/vidcache/test$x.mp4 -qscale:v 1
>   /var/vidcache/i$x.mpg

Does not work:

> sudo ffmpeg -i
>   concat:"i0.mpg|i1.mpg"
>   -qscale:v 1 /var/vidcache/output.mpg

/var/vidcache has 777 privs and `www-data` is in the sudoers file with NOPASSWD (yes, I know - this is just for debug purposes before I lock down security).

When I run the last command from a php script from the command line by itself, it DOES work. (Running as www-data or root.) But when I try to put it in a function called from a web page, it does NOT work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the answer was as stupid as "where does www-data know where to look for files?"

I was assuming a lot with the i0.mpg. It needs a fully qualified directory, obviously.

Anyway, changing the code to look like this worked:

> sudo ffmpeg -i concat:"/var/vidcache/i0.mpg|/var/vidcache/i1.mpg"
>   -qscale:v 1 /var/vidcache/output.mpg

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the third exec:

```
sudo ffmpeg -i "concat:i0.mpg|i1.mpg" -qscale:v 1 /var/vidcache/output.mpg
```

[Here](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files) is a good wiki page on how to concat media files in `ffmpeg`.